# I want to know the module through which any user can add his own tags for the content on the pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to know the module from D7 which i can use to add tags for the any content.
Suppose i have one page Guide for beginners
then on this page there is word "Guide"
So at the bottom of the page there should be Add tag option in which i can add the tag for the word "Guide".
once i tagged it should display at the bottom in my tags.
So this facility should be for any user.
Please let me know the module if any available or the method for implementing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/hashtags try this module

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to know how to use the Taxonomy module, which comes with Drupal core.

Good place to start would be its [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy).

Comment: ok. but when i create any new vocabulary terms its only from admin site.i needed to know how the normal user can tag the any content.

Comment: @user1656134 for that you should give the normal users appropriate permissions to edit the content. You do that at: `admin > people > permissions`

Comment: Taxonomy won't allow users to retag content when viewing it, which I believe is what the OP is after.

Comment: Hello let me explain the problem in detail.

Comment: Hello let me explain the problem in detail.I needed option on each content page.My tag in which user can tag any word he want from the content. for example if there is content page Documentation in which there is word 'Testing' so if user added the tag on the word "Testing" this page should be displayed when Testing tag got click. Also for the tagging there should be some input field.please let me know if there is any module i tried community tagging but its not registering tags at the back end.